# chrooting an application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chroot

I have an requirement that requires all applications running on a server in a DMZ to be chrooted.  How does one chroot an application using Ubuntu?  Are there any good online guides?

Answer (score 1):

There is no *one way* to move an application into a chroot jail. Each application has its own dependencies, shared library requirements, etc., all of which need to be taken into consideration when chrooting it.

If you have a specific application you need to chroot, then mention what it is and we can try and give more specific guidance.

Comment: I'd like to chroot apache2 webserver

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information.